# Размытие по гауссу. Решение "в лоб"

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, интересует реализация размытия по гауссу. Решение нужно именно самое простое, т.е. без свёрток и т.п.

Comment: идешь по двумерному массиву по строчкам, ставишь значение каждой точки - арифметическое среднее от 9ти соседних, кажется так.

Comment: @eicto - вернее совсем не по гауссу :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко, то идея в том, что вы, для каждого пикселя, двигаетесь лишь в одном направлении (можно и сразу в двух), полученные значения пикселей мы перемножаем на соответствующие позиции значения из "волшебного" массива, допустим:

```
 const float value[9] = {
     0.05, 0.09, 0.11, 0.15, 0.20, 0.15, 0.11, 0.09, 0.05
 };
```

и складываем все полученные значения, собственно все.

Сильно сомневаюсь что вы поймете, но я попытался :) Вот пример кода(простите, не delphi, GLSL)

```
uniform sampler2D screen;
uniform vec2 pixelSize;   // vec2( 1 / screenWidth, 1 / screenHeight )
uniform int isVertical;   // blur can be done in 2 direction, to get common
                          // blur effect you should pass a texture at least 2
                          // times (to blur vertically and horizontally)
// .....
vec4 blur(vec2 position) {
    vec2 xDelta = vec2(pixelSize.x, 0.0);
    vec2 yDelta = vec2(0.0, pixelSize.y);
    vec2 delta = pixelSize;
    vec4 result;
    const float value[9] = {
        0.05, 0.09, 0.11, 0.15, 0.20, 0.15, 0.11, 0.09, 0.05
    };
    if(isVertical == 1) {
        vec2 currentPosition = vec2(position.x, position.y - 4.0 * pixelSize.y);
        for(int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
            result += texture2D(screen, currentPosition) * value[i];
            currentPosition.y += pixelSize.y;
        }
    }
    else {
        vec2 currentPosition = vec2(position.x - 4.0 * pixelSize.x, position.y);
        for(int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
            result += texture2D(screen, currentPosition) * value[i];
            currentPosition.x += pixelSize.x;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void main() {
    vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy * pixelSize;
    gl_FragColor = blur(position);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте тут [Быстрое размытие по Гауссу](http://habrahabr.ru/post/151157/). Думаю адаптировать под дельфи труда не составит.